# What causes the wooden bridge on Vow to collapse?

Tags: lethal-company

The first time I played Vow with my friends, we sprinted across the wooden bridge that leads to the main entrance of the building and it collapse on us, leaving us badly wounded.  Since then, we've been crossing the bridge one at a time and that seems to work, but slows us down some. I later watched a video of a team cross the bridge at the same time without issue, leading me to believe there is something else to the bridge collapsing mechanic.

What causes the bridge to collapse on Vow? Is it random? Does weight play into it? When it did collapse on us, we all were carrying no items at the time.